# Export to PDF - Code does not create file

Tags: vba

I am trying to do the following - loop through an excel sheet, see where there is an email address, and then if there is an email address, create a pdf document.

The code that I have is

```
Function BatchRunMails()

Dim countrow As Integer, mailAddress As String, UniqueId As Integer
Dim Source As Object
Dim FixedFilePathName As String
Dim OverwriteIfFileExist As Boolean
Dim OpenPDFAfterPublish As Boolean
Dim FileFormatstr As String
Dim Fname As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet

countrow = 340




While Sheets(BilledSheet).Cells(countrow, "A") <> ""
    mailAddress = Sheets(BilledSheet).Cells(countrow, "D")
    If mailAddress <> "" Then
        UniqueId = Sheets(BilledSheet).Cells(countrow, "A")
        Sheets(StatementSheet).Activate
        Sheets(StatementSheet).Cells(3, "O").Activate
        Sheets(StatementSheet).Cells(3, "O") = UniqueId
        Sheets(InvoiceSheet).Activate
        Sheets(InvoiceSheet).Cells(3, "M").Activate
        Sheets(InvoiceSheet).Cells(3, "M") = UniqueId

        If Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles") & "\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE" _
         & Format(Val(Application.Version), "00") & "\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> ""   Then

Macro3
Macro2


            Set ws = ActiveSheet


           ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
           FileName:="C:\Users\c730057\Documents\02. Personal Folder\Saved PDF.pdf"










End If
End If

countrow = countrow + 1
Wend







End Function
```

At this stage it does not create the PDF file at all - it creates nothing. I have tried a number of different codes, but to no avail. 
Any Ideas?

Thank you

Comment: step through your code (while in VBA IDE place your cursor inside `BatchRunMails()` code and press F8, then keep pressing F8 to step to subsequent line code to be executed) and use Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it out) to query relevant variables values (e.g: type `?mailAddress` and press return)

Comment: Hi, I have done that, and all variables return the correct value, and it does get to the line       `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat     Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                 FileName:="C:\Users\c730057\Documents\02. Personal Folder\Saved PDF.pdf" ` but does nothing

Comment: you mean you don't get any file named after "Saved PDF.pdf" in folder named after "C:\Users\c730057\Documents\02. Personal Folder" ?

Comment: Correct - I get no file at all.

Comment: assuming `Macro3` and `Macro2` don't do any harm, your code works for me. Is it doing nothing right from the first processed file (i.e. when `countrow ` is 340) or afterwards?

Comment: Macro 2 and 3 are immaterial - have tried running the code without them - but still does nothing. Looks like it generates the file, but there is no file saved. Runs through the code error free. When I change to save as, the save as dialog appears, I select ok - and looks like it is saving, but again no file at all.

Comment: try changing output folder to a more  "open" one (like your "desktop"). but it's just a blind shot

Comment: Exactly what the issue was - thank you - changed the location and it worked

Comment: You are welcome